# Как брать при перезагрузке страницы, значение из localstorage?

Tags: javascript

Как брать при перезагрузке страницы, значение из localstorage вместо значения переменной "thisCount"?

```js
    var thisCount = 100;
    function countPeople() {
        const counterNum = document.querySelector('.counter__number');
        var countRandom = Math.floor((Math.random()*10) + 1);
        thisCount = thisCount + countRandom;
        // var localValue = localStorage.setItem('key', thisCount);
        console.log(thisCount);
    }
    setInterval(() => countPeople(), 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let localStorageItem = localStorage.getItem('key');
let thisCount = localStorageItem !== null ? localStorageItem  : 100;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Я слишком туп... Не могу понять что и куда вставлять (в какой последовательности, после каких строк)

Comment: Всё, сделал.....